# Crashes when Open browser in ACER Iconia

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an android app. In Which when I click on a button it opens a url in app browser.
It works fine on my Android device version 4.2. but when I do the same on Acer Iconia, my app crashes.

Code to open url in browser :

```
String url="https://www.google.com";
Intent browserintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserintent);
```

Is there any issue in code or its issue with the ACER Iconia.
Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your stack trace look like from logcat? hrrm???

Comment: It's issue reported by user, so I don't have stack trace.

Comment: I'd recommend a tool like Crittercism or a similar crash reporting tool, as there's no way to predict all the variations of Android and custom ROMs, etc out there that users can run on their machines. This way you always know when a user has a crash.